# Failed with error: HttpRequestException encountered. cannot spawn while trying to commit on github

Tags: github, pycharm

I changed some code on my project with PyCharm. When I tried to commit changed files to my github repository, it threw an error given below:

```
Failed with error: HttpRequestException encountered. cannot spawn C:\.PyCharmEdu4.0\system\tmp\intellij-git-askpass.bat: No such file or directory failed to execute prompt script (exit code 1) could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No error
```